# Zend framework 3 change document root no Vhost access

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm installing a zend 3 skeleton application on a cloudserver, but i can't change the apache Vhost. How to change the document root to the public folder?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create files in the host?

Also, the `FollowSymLinks` option must be enabled in the Apache config to make it work.

If this is the case, you could create a symlink with the same name as the folder used today as the document root pointing to the location you wish to use as the new root.

Example:

Actual Webroot: `/var/www/app`

1. Rename your actual doc: `mv /var/www/app /var/www/my_app`
2. Create symlink: `ln -s /var/www/my_app/public /var/www/app`
3. Restart apache: `service apache2 restart`

With my knowledge that's the only way without access to apache configuration, unfortunately.